# Show how many days left to expires

Tags: sql-server, vbscript

I am using the following code to show a "countdown" for 30 days from today:

`RIGHT(DateDiff("d", DBDATEFIELD+30, Now()),LEN(DateDiff("d", DBDATEFIELD+30, Now()))-1)`

Example: The news was created on `23/01`, so today it will show `25`.

The code is working, but I know it is not "right". How can this be done in the right way?

**EDIT: A SQL solution is appreciated, too.**

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

Comment: DATEDIFF(DAY,yourColumn,GETDATE())

Comment: ^ will show how many days from the date in yourColumn. I want to know how many dates left to 30 days after that date. Thanks. Update: `Stuff(DATEDIFF(DAY,yourColumn,GETDATE())-30, 1, 1, '')`

Comment: Did u get the solution? @Khrys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Stuff(DATEDIFF(DAY,yourColumn,GETDATE())-30, 1, 1, '')`